# Make iPad app fit in TV through HDMI

Tags: ipad, television, hdmi

I am working on an iPad application, and I have to give a demo on a television through HDMI, but iPad screen only appears in the middle of the TV screen.

How can I make my app fill the whole TV, without leaving black spaces on the sides?

I have seen another app that covers the whole screen of the TV.

Comment: we can only do it through HDMI

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2806158?start=30&tstart=0 might not be possible... if you are really bent on it maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846766/hdmi-video-into-an-ios-device

Comment: i have "Status Board" app. it works fine. it covers the whole screen in TV

Comment: status board may be using proprietary code though

Comment: Maybe this is helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097965/ios-external-hdmi-output-fills-only-half-the-screen-except-when-coding-view

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653285/black-bars-with-hdmi-adapter-on-ipad-2?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to mirror your iPad display onto the tv?

If that is the case then you cannot change the aspect ratio because you are mirroring your 1024x768 screen.

Status board is designed specifically to support a second screen and does not mirror the iPads display.. this is done because the second UIScreen has a size that supports the physical screen.

If you want to optimize your app to support a second screen then check this out: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html

Otherwise I'm aftaid you have to live with the black borders..

Think about it, if you tried mirroring your macs monitor onto an external display then this would still be the case

Comment: Not the exact answer. but i marked it accepted because you were right... finally i did it with new UIWindow